# Do students use Floo powder to come to school?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child, order-of-the-phoenix

In *The Cursed Child*, we see that Harry and Co. use Floo powder to come to Hogwarts and talk to McGonagall about Albus and Scorpius. This means that Floo Powder can be used to come in and out of Hogwarts. Even if *The Cursed Child* is not counted as one of the 'mainstream' books, in OOTP, we see that Sirius is able to use Floo Powder to talk to Harry.

From the above lines, it is quite evident that students may be able to use Floo Powder to come to, or get out of Hogwarts. Is there any mention in the books of students using Floo Powder to come to school?

Comment: It would be nice if someone could add relevant quotes to this question. :)

Comment: Might have been just in the movie but didn't Sirius use floo powder to talk to Harry at one point?

Comment: I'll have to check, but I'm pretty sure in HBP they use it to go back after Christmas. And I *think* it's mentioned as being for special/security reasons. IN OOTP they use it to go to Grimmauld Place when Mr Wesley has been injured, but that's obviously a one-off emergency.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix, I have mentioned that in the question. This happened in OOTP.

Comment: It was mentioned in ootp when Dumbledore denies the idea of Floo Network to send them to Grimmauld Place when Arthur Weasley was attacked. Then definitely the floo powder is there and someone like Fred and George might have tried it. Also, in some cases where they mention that the relatives came to Hogwarts to take their children away (or to visit them like Arthur and Molly came in cos), then they could use the Floo Network.

Answer (score -2):

it is stated that Hogwarts has pretty strong charms and other protections and magical travel is not possible, for eg you can't apparate into Hogwarts. so most likely it was not allowed. also Floo powder use could be easily regulated and registered by ministry.

Please check [this website](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Floo_Powder), it may clear your doubts.

Comment: I doubt this. In the Cursed Child, Harry used it to visit McGonagall in her office. And if it was OK then, I would hazard a guess that it was OK before.

Comment: it was said to be regulated that's why no one used floo powder in deathly hallows. also i used the info from link, did you check it.

Comment: Deathly Hallows is out of question. I never mentioned it as we did not know what happened in Hogwarts for the majority of the book.

Comment: i am not saying for hogwarts but in general, when they all take polyjuice and harry goes with hagrid, they couldn't use apparition and floo powder

Comment: 1) They can't use Apparition anyway while inside Hogwarts. 2) It was made ILLEGAL by MOM to connect that house to the Floo Network. That's why they couldn't use Floo.

Comment: oh ok thanks. but i am pretty sure somwhere in the books it was mentioned that the ministry keeps tab on floo powder. nevertheless, i am not sure how can they use floo powder inside hogwarts.